# How to Optimize below Active record query which returns no of records belonging to date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-optimization, rails-activerecord

I would like a optimized AR(ActiveRecord) query as my current AR query queries the DB many times

Assume a Model **Chocolate** with a column **created_at**.
I have the following AR Query in my controller:

```
for i in 1..4 
    @myHash[i] = Chocolate.where(created_at: (Time.now - i.hours)..(Time.now - (i-1).hours)).count    
end
```

The above query retrieves from the db 4 times(Assuming current time is  12:00)

```
Select COUNT(*) from Chocolate where created_at BETWEEN 11:00 AND 12:00
Select COUNT(*) from Chocolate where created_at BETWEEN 10:00 AND 11:00 
Select COUNT(*) from Chocolate where created_at BETWEEN 09:00 AND 10:00 
Select COUNT(*) from Chocolate where created_at BETWEEN 08:00 AND 09:00
```

How to change the query so that it retrieves from db only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a query like this:

```
Chocolate.where(Chocolate.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(4.hours.ago))
         .group("DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at)")
         .count
```

It is going to return a hash with the count of records grouped by hour.

```
{"2019-02-12 00:00:00"=>152, "2019-02-12 01:00:00"=>57, "2019-02-12 02:00:00"=>132, "2019-02-12 03:00:00"=>132}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fun thing I learned this week. If you want to do a >= query, you can do `Chocolate.where(created_at: 4.hours.ago..Float::INFINITY)`. I you wanted to do <=, then you could use `-Float::INFINITY` on the lower bound.

Comment: I am getting a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid DATE_TRUNC does not exist error.I am using MySQL db.Thanks for the quick Answer

Comment: I figured out that DATE_TRUNC is not available in MySQL, Instead i used hour(created_at). The final query is  Chocolate.where(Chocolate.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(4.hours.ago))
         .group("hour(created_at)")
         .count

Answer (score 0):

Try pure string condition:

```
Chocolate.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', (Time.now - i.hours), (Time.now - (i-1).hours))
```